# Crud and Services

Tags: java, spring, encapsulation

I'm working with Crud and Spring MVC, and get stuck with duplicating the same code with different repositories;

f.e. if i use Customers, Items  and Logins i have

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>{

}
```

but with Item i have the same stuff:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long>{

}
```

Furthermore there are same methods in repositories, like findAll(), findDistinctBy...(), deleteAll(), etc.

As I know the good practice is escaping of code duplication, but where i should do it? In service, using special service interface and implement it by special class, and then specialise the service for each entity? Or I should do it in the my custom repository as they said in official Spring Data JPA reference documentation [spring data reference $4.3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning)?

My variant for code with service is below.
Common interface for all entities

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MyCrudService<T>{

    <S extends CrudRepository<T, Long>> Iterable<T> findAll(S s);
}
```

Common class that realises the service

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public class MyCrudServiceImpl<T> implements MyCrudService<T>{

    @Override
    public <S extends CrudRepository<T, Long>> Iterable<T> findAll(S s) {
        return s.findAll();
    }
}
```

Special service class for Unit entity

```
@Service
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyUnitServiceTwo{

    UnitRepository unitRepository;
    MyCrudServiceImpl crudService;

    public List<Unit> findAll1() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(crudService.findAll(unitRepository));
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't recommend what you are doing. The main issue I can see is that underneath the wraps Spring is determining what to inject in to each repository and what meta links need to be created. In your approach you introduce possible errors in this chain and thus could experience huge issues later on.

Comment: While duplication of code is discouraged, in this instance you're not really duplicating code. As @MikeTung stated spring will want to know what its autowiring to make sure the bindings are correct and to reduce error. It also makes for better segregation of queries if you need to make custom or different queries for classes.

Comment: Thx for your posts. Sometimes spring seems too complicated also in the simple at a glance questions.

Comment: Which code do you think you are duplicating?